# Python "or" оператор не работает со словарем

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
test = {
    "2": 1
}

c = test["1"] or test["2"]
print(c)
```

Ошибка:

```
c = test["1"] or test["2"]
KeyError: '1'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: `c = test["1"] or test["2"]`... что вы хотите сделать в этой строке?

Comment: Очевидно, вы пытаетесь получить значение по несуществующему ключу, что и приводит к ошибке. Предварительно проверяйте, существует ли ключ в словаре (например через `if "1" in test`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То что вы хотите делается так:

```
c = test.get('1', test.get('2'))
```

Второй параметр в `get` будет возвращен, если ключ переданный в первом параметре не существует в словаре.

Или как вариант:

```
c = test.get('1') or test['2']
```

`get` в отличии от `[]` не бросает исключения, а вернет `None`, если ключа нет (действует аналогично `test.get('1', None)`, т.е. значение по умолчанию будет `None`).

У вас же исключение случается до того как `or` может что-то сделать.

Comment: "У вас же исключение случается до того как or может что-то сделать." Ах вот оно что! Благодарю!

Comment: @Lasna1 При этом, используя or, надо точно знать, что именно он вам нужен. Потому что если первый ключ существует, но хранит число 0, `test.get('1') or test.get('2')` выдаст значение второго.